# ¿Cómo puedo hacer uso de la propiedad UseSystemPasswordChar en otros TextBox que no son nativos de Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, contraseña, textbox

Estoy Utilizando Bunifu como Framework de diseño, para WindowsForms. Pero sus herramientas no tienen algunas funciones que tienen los textbox nativos. Quisiera saber como puedo cubrir la contraseña de otra manera, utilizando los textbox de Bunifu.
Lenguaje Utilizado: C#
----------------------PROPIEDADES DE BUNIFU TEXTBOX
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que BunifuTextbox no tiene la propiedad `PasswordChar` en versiones antiguas.

Recomendaban utilizar BunifuMaterialtextbox o BunifuMetroTextbox.